# Converting SQL statement to LinQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm new to Linq. and I'm trying to write this statement in SQL to Linq but I can't get it right.

SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    changes.CHG_NO, changes.CHG_DESC, 
    transport_requests.TRKORR, transport_requests.AS4TEXT 
FROM 
    dbo.changes 
CROSS JOIN 
    dbo.transport_requests 
WHERE 
    transport_requests.TRKORR = N'E81K900251' AND changes.CHG_NO = 1
```

I tried this:

```
var que = from c in db.changes
          from t in db.transport_requests
          where ((t.TRKORR == "E81K900251") && (c.CHG_NO == 1))
          select new { c.CHG_NO, c.CHG_DESC,t.TRKORR, t.AS4TEXT };
```

but it doesn't work.

No exception is thrown, it just comes back empty.

Can someone point to the right code?

Thanks.

This is the output I want to get:

```
CHG_NO     CHG_DESC      TRKORR         AS4TEXT
-----------------------------------------------
   1       test          E81K900251     Dummy
```

![Changes Table][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yoy1.png

![transport_requests][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQjhh.png

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Are you getting a syntax error? Exception? Unexpected result? Details...

Comment: are you familiar with the `JOIN` command in a linq query.. also are you wanting a CROSS JOIN or a INNER JOIN ? what is the common `Key` in db.Changes and db.transport_request from there an example on how to write this can be easier for someone to show you

Comment: The query look correct to me. You have to be more specific with what the problem is.

Comment: Ok I'll put it into words. I want to take 2 fileds (CHG_NO, CHG_DESC) from changes where CHG_NO = someNumber and 2 fileds(TRKORR,AS4TEXT) from transport_requests where TRKORR = "some string" and display the 4 of them in one row.

Comment: use equal in place of ==, until or unless you tell what is the exact error no one can help you.

Comment: @Tal You have to describe what the **problem** is.

Comment: There is no exception thrown. it just comes back empty.

Comment: @Tal You know the query isn't run until you evaluate it. For example by calling `.ToList()`.

Comment: if I add ToList() I get this:
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'BL.Cartdata.change get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the common keys between the two entities.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

```
var q = 
from c in categories 
join p in products on c equals p.Category 
select new { Category = c, p.ProductName };
```

notice "on c equals p.Category".

Comment: There is no any connection between the 2 tables.

Comment: There's your problem.

Comment: it can be done in MySQL so i believe that it can be done also in MSSQL. this is the PHP to MYSQL code:
   "SELECT CHG_NO, CHG_DESC, TRKORR, AS4TEXT FROM changes JOIN    transport_requests WHERE TRKORR = '" . "string" . "' AND CHG_NO = "    . int . "")

Comment: there has to be a common key to join. how is the db supposed to know which records from transport_requests line up with records from changes?

Comment: they don't need to be lined up with them. I only want to display 2 fileds from the same line of 1 table and the same for the other one. just display them in one table row on a browser.

Comment: 1 and "test" are in the same line in changes and "E81K900251" and "Dummy" are in the same line in transport_requests.

Comment: @Michael, there does not have to be a common key to do a cross join, by definintion you do not specify a key in SQl when doing a cross join because every record of table B joins with every record of table A.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to figure out what was the problem.

```
var que = from c in db.changes
          from t in db.transport_requests
          where ((t.TRKORR == "E81K900251") && (c.CHG_NO == change[0].CHG_NO))
          select new { c.CHG_NO, c.CHG_DESC,t.TRKORR, t.AS4TEXT };
```

In my original code I used Change[0].CHG_NO in the "where" part. when I used an array the EF tried to pull the entire array into the it's scope. I needed to store the value of change[0].CHG_NO into a variable and it solved my problem.

this is what I needed to do:

```
var change_0_CHG_NO = change[0].CHG_NO;
var que = from c in db.changes
          from t in db.transport_requests
          where ((t.TRKORR == "E81K900251") && (c.CHG_NO == change_0_CHG_NO))
          select new { c.CHG_NO, c.CHG_DESC,t.TRKORR, t.AS4TEXT };
```